# Https server works locally, not through internet with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, https

I'm kind of a new Apache user (version 2.4). I'm having trouble configuring the whole thing. My server has an IP address- `192.168.2.10`, for example my public IP is `123.123.123.123`. In my hosting provider website I did set an A record pointing at `123.123.123.123`. My Apache config looks like:

```
Listen 443

<VirtualHost _default_:433>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAdmin my@mail.com
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
```

The problem is I receive `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` all the time. When I tried swaping `www.example.com` with local IP `192.168.2.5` it KIND OF worked (SSL certificate problems because they are connected to `www.example.com`, but I managed to see HTTP response. Where seems to be the problem?

EDIT:

I think the problem is I can't use port `443` because it's my routers default managment port. How should I configure it then? I have NAT rule on my router that does forward every `:8456` request to `192.168.2.10:443`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It was "SSL 3.0" option turned off on my router.